# Neo4j indexing (with Lucene) - good way to organize node "types"?

Tags: java, lucene, indexing, neo4j

This is more actually more of a Lucene question, but it's in the context of a neo4j database.

I have a database that's divided into 50 or so node types (so "collections" or "tables" in other types of dbs).  Each has a subset of properties that need to be indexed, some share the same name, some don't.

When searching, I always want to find nodes of a specific type, never across all nodes.

I can see three ways of organizing this:

- One index per type, properties map naturally to index fields: index 'foo', `'id'='1234'`.
- A single global index, each field maps to a property name, to distinguish the type either include it as part of the value (`'id'='foo:1234'`) or check the nodes once they're returned (I expect duplicates to be very rare).
- A single index, type is part of the field name: `'foo.id'='1234'`.

Once created, the database is read-only.

Are there any benefits to one of those, in terms of convenience, size/cache efficiency, or performance?

As I understand it, for the first option neo4j will create a separate physical index for each type, which seems suboptimal.  For the third, I end up with most lucene docs only having a small subset of the fields, not sure if that affects anything.

Comment: Having a separate index for each type seems to be more convenient and also quicker, as the overall size of your index will be smaller. But I may be missing something.

Comment: @biziclop: It actually seemed like the least convenient to me, since I'd have to manage opening/closing the individual indices. My understanding is that the overall size will also be larger (see jpountz's answer).

Comment: @Dimitri Well, obviously the overall size will be larger, the question is: are searches for all types distributed evenly in time? Or are some types searched a lot more often than other? Either way, what I'd do is to implement the solution I find the most convenient and see if it performs well. If it does, you have your winner.

Comment: I agree, I'm just trying to figure out what I find the most convenient :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single index will be smaller than several little indexes, because some data, such as the term dictionary, will be shared. However, since a term dictionary lookup is a O(lg(n)) operation, a lookup in a bigger term dictionary might be a little slower. (If you have 50 indexes, this would only require 6 (2^6>=50) more comparisons, it is likely you won't notice any difference.)

Another advantage of a smaller index is that the OS cache is likely to make queries run faster.

Instead of your options 2 and 3, I would index two different fields `id` and `type` and search  for (`id`:ID AND `type`:TYPE) but I don't know if it is possible with neo4j.

Comment: Using multiple fields is possible, but a little less natural (which is why I left that out): you can pass an implementation-specific query string directly to the index engine. I would prefer to use the more general `index.get(field, value)` API.

Comment: Then I would pick the 2nd option which is most natural (id:TYPE+ID)

Answer (score 2):

I came across this problem recently when I was building an `ActiveRecord` connection adapter for Neo4j over REST, to be used in a Rails project. Since `ActiveRecord` and `ActiveRelation`, both, have a tight coupling with SQL syntaxes, it became difficult to fit everything into  NoSQL. Might not be the best solution, but here's how I solved it:

1. Created an index named `model_index` which indexed nodes under two keys, `type` and `model`
2. Index lookup with `type` key currently happens with just one value `model`. This was introduced primarily to achieve a `SHOW TABLES` SQL functionality which can get me a list of all models present in the graph.
3. Index lookup with `model` key takes place with values corresponding to different model names in my system. This is primarily for achieving `DESC <TABLENAME>` functionality.
4. With each table creation as in `CREATE TABLE`, a node is created with table definition attributes being stored in node properties.
5. Created node is indexed under `model_index` with `type:model` and `model:<model-name>`. This enables the newly created model in the list of 'tables' and also allows one to directly reach the model node by an index lookup with `model` key.
6. For each record created per `model` (type in your case), an outgoing edge is created labeled `instances` directed from model node to this new record. `v[123] :=> [instances] :=> v[245]` where v[123] represents model node and v[245] represents a record of v[123]'s type.
7. Now if you want to get all instances of a specified type, you could lookup the `model_index` with `model:<model-name>` to reach a model node and then fetch all adjacent nodes over an outgoing edge labeled `instances`. Filtered lookups can be further achieved by applying filters and other complex traversals.

The above solution prevents model_index from clogging since it contains 2x  and achieves an effective record lookup via one index lookup and single-level traversal.

Although in your case, nodes of different types are not adjacent to each other, even if you wanted to do so, you could determine the type of any arbitrary node by simply looking up it's adjacent node with an incoming edge labeled `instances`. Further, I'm considering the incorporate SpringDataGraph's pattern of storing a `__type__` property on each instance node to avoid this adjacent node lookup.

I'm currently translating AREL to Gremlin scripts for almost everything. You could find the source code for my AR Adapter at https://github.com/yournextleap/activerecord-neo4j-adapter

Hope this helps, Cheers! :)

Comment: This sounds like my option "2b": index everything together, and use the graph to filter for type (either with an edge check, or, as you suggest, a type property). I think I'm leaning toward option 3, so that the filtered lookup can be done entirely in the index.

Comment: One drawback of relying too much on indexes is that when you need to export your graph, either in a GraphML or GraphSON, none of which retain indexes, you need to regenerate indexes when you import your graph elsewhere. Indexing everything on the graph could mean a high  turn-around time for export->import. Also, if there's a subgraph which is disconnected from the root node, losing out on indexes in such a case might mean losing of data and you're left without a foolproof option to reach the subgraph.

Comment: I shall hence advise that you have all your nodes traversable from the root node, in case you happen to import the graph from a previously exported GraphML/SON.

Comment: Yes, my graph is set up pretty much the way you describe: `ref-->type-->instance`.  There's actually one more level of organization - the types are grouped into "datasets" (it makes more sense in the actual schema, "type" may be a bad name for it), but the idea is the same.  This is a pretty specialized db, optimized for a few specific search operations, so I'm not too worried about export/import (it's too big for that, anyway). Seems that if I can do the value lookups without also hitting the edge store, that's the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

spring-data-neo4j is using the first approach - it creates a different index for each type. So I guess that's a good option for the general scenario. But in your particular case it might be suboptimal, as you say. I'd run some benchmarks to measure the performance.

The other two, by the way, seem a bit artificial. You are possibly indexing completely unrelated information in the same index, which doesn't sound right.

Comment: Not sure I see the problem with indexing unrelated data together - had this been a relational database, for example, most of these properties would likely be indexed in a single 'attribute-value' table.

Comment: yeah, you may be right. For a full-text indexing it's strange, but as you are using it as an index backing the neo4j store, doesn't sound that bad.