# Neo4j - Single Lucene index or one per user?

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I need some help deciding on the right indexing strategy for my Neo4j database. In the database I have users who have items and every user and item has a modified epoch integer value and a UUID value (a trimmed Base64 String). I'm developing on 2.0-M6 so I can use the new [schema](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html) based indexing nicely to query users on the "uuid" field of label USER.

But indexing users' items is more complicated. I want to do both queries of type "userUUID=X AND modified > Y", which should return all items that have a modified integer that is larger (are more recent) than the number Y. But I also want to do a simple search "userUUID=X, itemUUID=Z", which should return a single node.

1. In my current very limited understanding of Lucene, probably the best solution would be one index with three keys "userUUID, itemUUID, modified" which would allow me to query it with a [compound query](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-lucene-extras.html#indexing-lucene-compound). But how exactly would I create such an index, and will it remain fast as my user base grows? The index should primarily be optimized on the userUUID property, which is in every query and only after that on the itemUUID and modified integer. Is that possible?
2. The other option is to build one index per user for the modified values and then one with a joined key "userUUID+itemUUID" for the direct item access. This is much easier to implemented than option 1, because a single key index is very well supported and documented by Neo4j. But if I have say a million users, will the index lookup for index "modified-items-for-X" still be fast, and will all those indexes eat up all my memory?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879457/neo4j-indexing-with-lucene-good-way-to-organize-node-types) question is related but there the number of Lucene indecies is much smaller.

EDIT. As Stefan guessed, the user and item are linked with an OWNS relationship, and UUID's are unique for every node in the database.

To further clarify, I'm looking for the most performant solution for querying items: a single user is expected to have thousands of items, and the "userUUID=X AND modified > Y" query will be issued by every user at a steady pace (even once per minute), as will the "userUUID=X and itemUUID=Y" query. So every millisecond counts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I ended up going with option 1, and created a three key index for items (in Scala):

```
val itemsIndex = neo4j.gds.index().forNodes("items")
itemsIndex.add(itemNode, "user", userUUID)
itemsIndex.add(itemNode, "item", itemNode.getProperty("uuid"))
itemsIndex.add(itemNode, "modified", new ValueContext(getProperty("modified").asInstanceOf[Long] ).indexNumeric())
```

and then querying it with:

```
itemsIndex.query( "user:\"" + userUUID) + "\" AND item:\"" + itemUUID)+ "\"")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Neo4j 2.0 schema indexes are limited to a single property, but you can create multiple indexes per label. I'm assuming you're using labels `User` and `Item` and your users have a `OWNS` relationship to their items. Further assumption is that uuids are really unique and not shared by multiple nodes. In this case I would not index the `modified` property. There's just a index on the uuids:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :User(userUuid)
CREATE INDEX ON :Item(itemUuid)
```

Remember: a index should be used for finding the start points of a traversal.

To find all items for user X with `modfied > y` use:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:OWNS]->(item:Item)
WHERE user.userUuid={X} and item.modified > {Y]
RETURN item
```

To find a specific item, it's just:

```
MATCH (item:Item) 
WHERE item.itemUuid={uuid}
RETURN item
```

If you really need compound index, you can use [legacy indexing](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html) - but schema indexes are way more comfortable.

Also be aware that as of this writing  2.0 is a milestone build which means it's not production ready.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! As I commented on the question, the queries are extremely frequent, and every user is expected to have up to hundreds of thousands of items. Can traversing all of those nodes to find the ones with the right modified value really be the fastest implementation?

Comment: Generally Neo4j can do ~1M/sec basic traversals per core, basic traversal is jumping from one node to one of its neighbors. This number is without property access - so it might be reasonable fast.

Comment: Another idea would be to denormalize a little bit and store the `userUuid` also on the the item node and establish a legancy index on `userUuid`, `itemUuid` and `modified`. This might be faster at runtime but more expensive at development time.

Comment: Thanks, storing the userUUID on the item node sounds interesting. However, can't I specify the keys on the three key index however I want, i.e. can't I leave the userUUID out of the actual item node and just put it programatically on the index every time I create a new item? And furthermore, how exactly do I create such an index in Java with an embedded Neo4j?

Comment: sure you can do that, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html for more info